# How to download a video file from a remote server in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file, video, download

I have 3 server 1 for api, 1 for content, 1 for frontend. I want to download a mp4 video file when i click in frontend. Basic flow- Frontend button click to download then call an api, and in api download a file. Here what i have already tried-

#### Frontend

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-hover iq-button iq-btn-sm"  download href="{{config('app.base_api_url').'/downloadAFile?url='.getsinglecontentvideobaseurl().$video->filename.'.'.$video->filetype.'&filetype=video/'.$video->filetype.'&filename='.$video->filename.'.'.$video->filetype.'"'}}">
    Download
</a>
```

#### Api

```
public function downloadAFile(Request $request)
{
    $url = $request->url ?? '';
    $filename = $request->filename ?? 'download.mp4';
    $filetype = $request->filetype ?? 'video/mp4';

    $file = $url;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: '.$filetype);
    return Response::download($file, $filename, $headers);  
}
```

##### When i click download getting this error-

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: _"Here what i have already tried"_ - and? What happened? What problem still needs solving?

Answer (score 0):

###### This api code works only $url is external online server. Otherwise it won't work. File name can't contain epmpty space.

```
    public function downloadAFile(Request $request)
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

        $url = $request->url ?? '';
        $filename = $request->filename ?? 'download.mp4';

        $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $filename);
        copy($url, $tempImage);

        return response()->download($tempImage, $filename);
    }
```